# ESP32 Preferences on partition `app1`

Tags: esp32

My Arduino ESP32 project needs a lot of space for on-device string storage and the default `nvs` partition is not enough. I'd like to use `app1` partition for preferences via `pref.begin("ns1", false, "app1")` but the device doesn't boot if I do that:

```
21:01:54.643 -> ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
21:01:54.643 -> Build:Mar 27 2021
21:01:54.643 -> rst:0x3 (RTC_SW_SYS_RST),boot:0x2b (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
21:01:54.643 -> Saved PC:0x403cdada
21:01:54.643 -> SPIWP:0xee
21:01:54.643 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
21:01:54.643 -> load:0x3fce3808,len:0x44c
21:01:54.643 -> load:0x403c9700,len:0xbd8
21:01:54.660 -> load:0x403cc700,len:0x2a80
21:01:54.660 -> entry 0x403c98d0
21:01:54.660 -> ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
... repeats
```

Any ideas on how to make it work?

I'd like to avoid defining a new partition since the code will be used by other people and ideally I'd avoid having them deal with another piece of complexity of redefining partitions.